# WebRequest Async CallBack Code only gets call the first time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous, webrequest

I am an absolute beginner on ASP.net (VB.) Please pardon me if the question is too obvious for the experienced members.

I tried to make a simple WebRequest in the async mode in case the target URL takes long to provide the data. In my code below, I just want to see if the callback block (RespCallback) is called correctly every time. If all goes well, lblResult should have the string '123' appended to it every time I click the button which calls the 'GetData' sub.

However, the lblResult only shows 123 after the first click. After the subsequent click, the lblResult only gets appended with '12', as if RespCallback is never called. When I tried to debug this in Visual Studio, the execution actually stepped right into the RespCallback part and the lblResult.Text watch actually shows '123123' but the resulting Web page always shows only '12312'

I am sure I am missing something basic here, but I just don't know what. I was even guessing that it has to do with browser cache (hence the result changes for the second time) but I don't know how to fix that either.

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

Jim

```
Dim myWebRequest As WebRequest

Public Shared allDone As New ManualResetEvent(False)
Private Shared BUFFER_SIZE As Integer = 1024

Public Class RequestState
    ' This class stores the state of the request
    Private Shared BUFFER_SIZE As Integer = 1024
    Public requestData As StringBuilder
    Public bufferRead() As Byte
    Public request As WebRequest
    Public response As WebResponse
    Public responseStream As Stream

    Public Sub New()
        bufferRead = New Byte(BUFFER_SIZE) {}
        requestData = New StringBuilder("")
        request = Nothing
        responseStream = Nothing
    End Sub ' New
End Class ' RequestState

Public Sub GetData(Sender As Object, Args As System.EventArgs)
    lblResult.Text += "1"
    myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(dataURL)

    Dim myRequestState As New RequestState()

    myRequestState.request = myWebRequest

    ' Start the asynchronous request.
    Dim asyncResult As IAsyncResult = CType(myWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(AddressOf RespCallback, myRequestState), IAsyncResult)


    lblResult.Text += "2"
    allDone.WaitOne()

End Sub

Private Sub RespCallback(asynchronousResult As IAsyncResult)
    lblResult.Text += "3"
    allDone.Set()
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds silly but maybe your label actually contains '123123' but layout is getting trimmed and you just don't see the full value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know VB so it's hard to read for me but I'm suspecting `GetData` is your `onClick` handler.

First thing that is not right is that you have `Shared` members. Why your reset event is `Shared`? It makes all requests use the same object.
Basically Your code with `ManualResetEvent` won't work because after first `allDone.Set()`, your object remains set (as long as web application lives). To get "123" every time you should add `allDone.Reset()` after `allDone.WaitOne()`.
In Your situation web request returns to client before `RespCallback` is called every time except first call (when your reset event is in non-signaled state).
`AutoResetEvent` resets automatically. That's why it worked.

But! You can't do this this way. Making your `ResetEvent` `Shared` you make all request use the same object. When more than one request will be processed by your application at the same time you will get undetermined behavior.

Remove Shared from your code. Than your code will work (but not asynchronously) without allDone.Reset() and without AutoResetEvent. But it will provide known results (not depending on amount of requests).

About asynchronous call (now that we have code "working"). Well. There is no async request to your web page. `allDone.WaitOne()` waits until your async webRequest finish. So basically you could just as well do synchronous request.

You need a special pattern for asynchronous web pages. You can read how to do this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx).

But i'm not sure it's what you wanted. Do you want your request to be called asynchronously so that it will not use server resources or do you want to display some message to the user (like "Data is being downloaded...") while your web page will remain fully responsible?

If it's the second one you should use AJAX functionality (Like `UpdatePanel` or using JavaScript directly). You can read about it [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax).

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz. I have followed your suggestions and now I get "123" every time. I am still a bit new to this whole async thing and still don't understand what the WaitOne() would do for me in this case if I am not going to get anything async anyways? But within the scope of the original question, you have answered the question completely. I can't vote your answer up yet as I am too new to the board. Will keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to check:

1. If your label is a fixed width, then it's possible the text is being clipped
2. If you are using an UpdatePanel, you will need to set its mode to 'Conditional' and call `Update()` on it in the RespCallback callback method so that the UI gets refreshed with the latest label text value.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Grzegorz Wilczura and Jeremy. I have checked the control and ensured that the label is not a fixed width. I can keep hitting the button and the label gets appended with 12 12 12 for many times (as opposed to 123 123.)

Comment: Also, I am using the ASP:Label, not TextBox or UpdatePanel. I have also tried changing it to a TextBox just to test and it yielded the same result. These controls are nested under asp:Content but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: One observation is that maybe the server doesn't wait for the callback to serve the label.Text value to the browser. Maybe they are on separate threads that do not wait? I say this because only some times I do get the 123 at the first time I press the button. My suspicion is that the times I do get '123' are the times the Web server responsed with the answer fast enough BEFORE the page gets served to the browser (when the callback code already changed the label.Text value to '123') The other times the value of the label.Text is still '12' and the page gets served before the callback code runs.

Comment: I got further. I changed the ManualResetEvent(False) on line #3 to AutoResetEvent(False). Now I get 123 every time. But that doesn't solve my problem totally. The calling to the Web service is now 'async'. But the GUI doesn't get updated while I wait for the call. In other words, the 123 will come all at once, not 12 and then 3 when the callback occurs. Can someone shed some light on how I get the GUI updated (or execute other tasks) while I wait for the callback (which is the whole point of doing this to begin with.)