# Calling WCF in async manner from ASP.Net will return worker thread to thread pool of ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asynchronous

I am trying to make my ASP.Net website more scalable, **but not sure if the ASP.Net thread receiving the web request is returned to thread pool before the async call to WCF method completes** Or this thread will wait for async call to finish.

The async call to WCF method takes about 20 to 40 seconds to complete.

**Edit 1 :** My code is as below for the page code-behind from where I am calling an async WCF method. The WCF method is async on WCF side, and it is also being called in an async manner from this page code-behind.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ABCService.ServiceClient sc = new ABCService.ServiceClient())
        {
           // List<ABCService.Product> products = sc.GetDocSummary("Vend1", null, false);//this is synchronous call from client
          sc.BeginGetProducts("Vend1",GetProductsCallback, sc);//this is asynchronous call from WCF
        }
    }

    protected void GetProductsCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        List<ABCService.Product> products = ((ABCService.ServiceClient)asyncResult.AsyncState).EndGetProducts(asyncResult); //this will call the WCF EndGetProducts method
    }
```

Comment: Are you using asynchronous ASP.NET page? Can you show some code from your page?

Comment: Ladislav - I have posted my code under Edit 1 in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your thread will be returned to the thread pool because your request will finish after `sc.BeginGetProducts`.
Method `GetProductsCallback` will not have input on request being processed.

You should read my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787825/webrequest-async-callback-code-only-gets-call-the-first-time/10804018#10804018). It's similar to Your problem.

In short: to achieve what You want you must use asynchronous web pages.
If You are using .Net 4.5 You should loot at [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45).

Comment: Grzegorz - I found as per my answer  below, that even when Async ="false" for Page, the callback method is still getting called on a different thread. So I am still getting the benefit of thread being returned when page is not Async.

Comment: Of course. But if You want to display result to requesting client this approach is useless. Unless You don't and You want to send Your product list by email or do something entirely else with it. Then sure. You would benefit from this approach. All depends on Your desired design.

Comment: Grzegorz -I found that even when using async page, html does not get sent to browser while the async operation is in progress. So the page will still be processing and we can only display to user when async operation has ended. I tried this on my laptop. Async pages are only to allow for better scalability, and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer which is explained in detail below.

I found that the threadid given by System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId was different for 'sc.BeginGetProducts' method as compared to  the threadid for method 'GetProductsCallback'.

**So it seems logical to conclude that the original ASP.Net worker thread was being returned to the thread pool, and a new thread from thread pool was being used for callback.**

*However, even though the original thread is returned to thread pool, this does not mean that the page will render on browser-side.* The page will render only after the callback method gets executed.

I initially thought that the page would render on browser-side after an async call is made but before the callback method is called, since the UI should not be blocking in case of async WCF calls. Here, its more appropriate to say that the 'worker thread (and not UI) is non-blocking when making async WCF calls from ASP.Net app'.

**Another interesting feature I found was that even when Page is NOT Async** i.e. Async="false" in page directive, I still saw two different thread ids being used for callback method and the original WCF call. So we still get the non-blocking benefit of using asyn WCF methods in our normal non-async pages.

Comment: Someone, please mark this post also as an answer, as I think my post and Grzegorz post are both valid answers.